# Access equivalent for T.INV.2T Excel ( two-tailed inverse ) function

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, statistics, vba

Is there any way of getting the equivalent of the two-tailed inverse function without hard coding it? My goal is to apply Grubbs test on my dataset so any ideas towards that direction more than welcome

Comment: Have you tried calling it within your macro?  foo = Application.WorksheetFunction.T_Inv_2T(arg1,arg2)

Comment: I have a vba module that runs solely from Access DB and adding anything external is not an option.